# class of processes guaranteed to exceed any thresholds

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Is it correct to say that any martingale (e.g., a GBM or anything similar), taking values in some real state space and not converging to a degenerate random variable, has the property that, given a value $y$ in that space, the probability of going above it once (and, therefore, infinitely many times), no matter where we start from, is $1$ as time diverges?

Can I correctly say the same holds for semimartingales, and, in general, what is the most general family of processes that, if I start from any value, I will always be able to both exceed any value $y_2$ and also go below any value $y_1$ ($y_1 < y_2$) of its state space, at least once, with a probability of $1$, as time goes to infinity?

What is a formal justification for these facts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This holds for martingales with $\langle M \rangle_\infty = \infty$. Suppose that $M$ is a such a martingale, then by the [Dambis-Dubins-Schwarz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubins%E2%80%93Schwarz_theorem), $M_t$ is a time-changed Brownian motion. In particular,

$$P\left(\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} M_s \geq a \right) = P\left(\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} B_{\left\langle M\right\rangle_s} \geq a \right) \to 1$$ as $t \to \infty$, since Brownian motion is recurrent.

Comment: Thank you, Jose that is very interesting I will go study the theorem you indicated to: "all continuous local martingales and martingales are time-changed Brownian motions". Since semimartingales intuitively add a random jump component, (my) intuition would suggest that the result could still hold. Is there a simple proof or justification beyond intuition that we can go beyond any upper and lower value inside the state space? It seems to me that requiring a nonvanishing variance should also be necessary (e.g., a process using the relative frequency of bernoulli trials).

Comment: (I meant "relative frequency of successes")

Comment: @Jada well, not quite: semimartingales also have a drift component you have to account for. This drift term can be tinkered with to prevent the process from hitting some far off targets, so I'm not quite sure what one can say generally

Comment: I see. But Brownian motion can also have drift (and scaling), but that did not spoil recurrence (?). Adding semimartingale jumps would not seem to hurt recurrence. As far as the final distribution allows the process value (e.g., the price of a stock) to move in the space state (and the variance of the limit distribution remains constant or increases), I would tend to imagine the price could cross any threshold. Sure, a drift up would make it more difficult to cross a bottom threshold for instance. But difficult may not be impossible asymptotically (?).

Comment: @Jada Indeed, you can still have a drifting semimartingale that is recurrent; what I meant is that you would need some condition on the drift to ensure that the resulting process remains so. I don't know what such a condition would look like.